# Having problems finding the error mentioned below that keeps program from running

Tags: java

I'm having some problems running the program. Whenever, I try I get the java.util.InputMismatchException. 
After searching about it, I noticed that it's when I try to get data but the next data isn't of that format ( in beginner terms ).
I've tried multiple times to find what is causing the error, but I can't seem to find it :/

And for those who find this to be sloppy, since arrays aren't used. I am not allowed to use them for this particular assignment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Huang_Grading
{
    //Global variables
    private static int holdMinStudentID;
    private static int holdMinEnhStudentID;
    private static int holdMaxStudentID;
    private static int holdMaxEnhStudentID;
    private static int holdModeStudentID;
    private static int holdModeEnhStudentID;

    /**Main method to pull data from*/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Set up input file
        File inputFile = new File("gradeInput.txt");

        validateFile(inputFile);
        validateData(inputFile);
        printData();
    }

    /**Read in file location, give error message if file does not exist
       Also, save valid numbers to an output file*/

    /**Compute and return mean of all grades*/
    public static double mean(Boolean gradeType) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner("outputs.txt");

        //Declare variables
        double finalMean = 000.00;
        double earnedGrade;
        int enhancedGrade;
        double totalEnhancedGrade = 0;
        double totalEarnedGrade = 0;
        int studentID;
        int lines = 0;

        //Mean grade
        while(fileInput.hasNext())
        {
            studentID = fileInput.nextInt();
            enhancedGrade = fileInput.nextInt(); 
            earnedGrade = fileInput.nextDouble();

            if(gradeType == false)
            {
                totalEarnedGrade = totalEarnedGrade + earnedGrade;
            }
            if(gradeType == true)
            {
                totalEarnedGrade = totalEarnedGrade + earnedGrade;
                totalEnhancedGrade = totalEnhancedGrade + enhancedGrade;
            }
            lines++;
            if(gradeType == false)
            {
                finalMean = totalEarnedGrade/lines;
            }
            if(gradeType == true)
            {
                finalMean = (totalEnhancedGrade + totalEarnedGrade)/lines;
            }
        }
        fileInput.close();
        return finalMean;
    }

    /**Compute and return minimum/maximum of all grades*/

    /**Print out results*/
    public static void printData() throws IOException
    {
        //Declare variables
        Boolean earned = false;
        Boolean enhanced = true;

        double meanEarnedGrade = mean(earned);
        double meanEnhancedGrade = mean(enhanced);

        System.out.printf("%25s%7.2f", "Mean Earned Grade:\n", meanEarnedGrade);
        System.out.printf("%25s%7.2f", "Mean Enhanced Grade:\n", meanEnhancedGrade);
    }
}
```

[image: error]

[image: outputs.txt]

Comment: @ScaryWombat Would that mean it would skip over part of it? I didn't learn catch yet in my class.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Is what you were asking for the update I made in main post?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I updated the main post ~ It's pretty much lines of numbers. My first one is an integer of 00000-99999, second one is an integer of 0-5, and last is double 000.00-100.00

Comment: @ScaryWombat Um..I end up with another error which is NoSuchElementException: No Line Found.
So I'm assuming dat wasn't the error?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's still the same line. I've tried various changes, but it keeps having problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is

change

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner("outputs.txt");
```

to

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File ("outputs.txt"));
```